# Linked List Delete Node , Simple linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list, erase

I'm trying to implement a function that deletes nodes from a linked list. So far, I can delete just the first node of the list(3).

I tried to go to the for loop from delete, I thought that the memory is not well allocated, I have been struggling for a few days and I don't understand, please help me a little, it's the topic I received from college.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct nod
{
    int key;
    struct nod *urm;
} NOD;

NOD *first=0,*last=0;

void add(int x)
{
    NOD *p=(NOD*)malloc(sizeof(NOD));
    p->key=x;
    p->urm=0;
    if(0==first)
    {
        first=p;
        last=p;
    }
    else{
        last->urm=p;
        last=p;
    }
}

void delete(int x)
{
    NOD *q,*p;
    if(first->key==x)
    {
        p=first;
        first=first->urm;
        free(p);

    }
    else{
        for(p=q=first;p=0;q=p,p=p->urm)
        {
            if(p->key==x)
            {
            q->urm=p->urm;
            if(p==last)
            {
                last=q;
            }
            free(p);
            }
        }
    }
}

void show()
{
    for(NOD *p=first;p!=0;p=p->urm)
    {
        printf("%d ",p->key);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    add(3);
    add(1);
    add(2);
    add(5);
    show();

    delete(2);
    show();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not a C++ code. It is a C code.

Comment: How is this a __linked__ list and not a usual array?

Comment: Extending on @VladfromMoscow: In C++ `delete` is a reserved keyword, you wouldn't be allowed to name a function that way (for instance...).

Comment: `for(p = q = first; p = 0; q = p, p = p->urm)` – have you noticed assignment instead of comparison? You used Yoda-style before, why not here, too? Compiler would have complained about then (didn't it at least issue a warning?).

Comment: The best way to understand linked lists (and other graph structures) is to visualize them. Pull out some paper, sharpen up a pencil, and DRAW the sucker. Draw your way step by step through each operation you need to perform. Use the drawings as the basis for the code and the expected when debugging. If you cannot follow your code and draw the exact same thing not only do you have a bug, but you'll quickly find out where AND probably know what you should have done instead.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the code you showed is not a C++ code. It is a C code.

It is a bad idea to define global variables like `first` and `last` and when functions depend on global variables. In this case you can not create more than one list in a program.

As for the function `delete` then in general it has undefined behavior. It can be called for an empty list.

Moreover in this ;loop

```
for(p=q=first;p=0;q=p,p=p->urm)
```

there is a typo in the condition expression. You are using the assignment operator instead of the comparison operator.

And you function ignore the case when the list contains only one node because in this case it does not update the last node.

Nevertheless using your approach the function delete can look the following way.

```
void delete(int x)
{
    if ( first )
    {
        if ( first->key == x )
        {
            NOD *tmp = first;
            first = first->urm;

            free( tmp );

            if ( first == NULL ) last = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            NOD *p = first;
            while ( p->urm != NULL && p->urm->key != x )
            {
                p = p->urm;
            }

            if ( p->urm != NULL )
            {
                NOD *tmp = p->urm;
                p->urm = p->urm->urm;

                free( tmp );

                if ( p->urm == NULL ) last = p;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct nod
    {

    int key;
    struct nod *urm;
    } NOD;

    NOD *first=0,*last=0;


    void add(int x)
    {

    NOD *p=(NOD*)malloc(sizeof(NOD));
    p->key=x;
    p->urm=0;
    if(0==first)
    {
        first=p;
        last=p;
    }
    else{
        last->urm=p;
        last=p;
    }

    }

void delete(int x)
{
    if ( first )
    {
        if ( first->key == x )
        {
            NOD *tmp = first;
            first = first->urm;

            free( tmp );

            if ( first == NULL ) last = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            NOD *p = first;
            while ( p->urm != NULL && p->urm->key != x )
            {
                p = p->urm;
            }

            if ( p->urm != NULL )
            {
                NOD *tmp = p->urm;
                p->urm = p->urm->urm;

                free( tmp );

                if ( p->urm == NULL ) last = p;
            }
        }
    }
}  

    void show()
    {
        for(NOD *p=first;p!=0;p=p->urm)
        {
            printf("%d ",p->key);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    int main()
    {
        add(10);
        add(20);
        add(30);
        add(40);

        show();

        delete(30);
        show();

        add( 50 );
        add( 60 );
        add( 70 );
        add( 80 );
        show();

        delete(80);
        show();


    return 0;
    }
```

Its output is

```
10 20 30 40 
10 20 40 
10 20 40 50 60 70 80 
10 20 40 50 60 70
```

Comment: works, but deletes the next digit, for example put the first digit, deletes the first (3), puts the next digit (1), deletes the 3rd (2)

Comment: @Mikey I run the following sequence of statements         delete(2);
        show();

        delete(3);
        show();

        delete(5);
        show();

        delete(1);
        show();
 and I git the expected result 3 1 2 5 
3 1 5 
1 5 
1

Comment: @Mikey Or do you mean to delete all nodes equal to the given value?

Comment: I want to add the digit and delete the selected digit, as in the example:

add (10);
add (20);
add (30);
add (40);
show ();

Delete (30);
show ();

the result fiind;

10, 20 ,40 
 
and

add (50);
add (60);
add (70);
add (80);
show ();

Delete (80);
show ();

the result fiind 50, 60, 70 

the final result fiind 

10 20 30 40
10 20 40

50 60 70 80
50 60 70

Comment: @Mikey I have  not understood how you got the result. After your inputs and deletions the result be 10 20 40 50 60 70. In fact you inserted the following elements  10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 and deleted only two values 30 and 80. So what is the problem?!

Comment: the problem is it doesn't delete my selected digit, it deletes the next one

Comment: @Mikey You wrote two calls of delete: delete( 30 ) and delete( 80 ) and these values were deleted. I do not know what else code you are using but if you are using only the function add, delete and  show then the result will be correct. Maybe you coped and pasted the shown function delete incorrectly.

Comment: I will use it like this, thank you for all the help and time given

Comment: @Mikey See my updated post. There is a demonstrative program and there is shown its result. I entirely do not understand what you are saying about. The program produces a correct result.

Comment: You helped me a lot and thank you, it works, and I appreciate the work, it works well

Comment: I made a mistake without realizing it, sorry for the headache, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can greatly simplify deleting a node from your list by using both a *pointer-to-pointer* to `NOD` and a *pointer-to* `NOD` to iterate over the list. This allows you to set the node at the current address to the `node->urm` eliminating the need to keep track of the previous node in the list, e.g.

```
/** delete node with key v from list (for loop) */
void delete (int v)
{
    NOD **ppn = &first;        /* pointer to pointer to first*/
    NOD *pn = first;            /* pointer to first */

    for (; pn; ppn = &pn->urm, pn = pn->urm) {
        if (pn->key == v) {
            *ppn = pn->urm;     /* set node at address to next node */
            free (pn);          /* free deleted node */
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

See [Linus on Understanding Pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/) for further discussion on the advantages of using the address of a node in addition to a pointer to node.

Answer (score -1):

I think your for loop condition is incorrect inside delete functions:

```
for(q=first, p=first->urm; p!=0; q=p, p=p->urm)
```

just change the condition, then it should work.

Comment: same problem , delete just the first node of the list