# When vscode runs a c language program, it gets stuck on a statement

Tags: c

After I enter numbers in the terminal, the program gets stuck at the free(temp) command line as shown.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BycHf.png

The program does not work properly until the "Continue" button is clicked twice.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDO2b.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gqzN.png

The source code is as follows：

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Node{  
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* head;



void Insert(int n){
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));
    temp->data = n;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;

}

void Delete(int z){
struct Node* temp = head;

    if(z == 1){
        head = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return;
    }
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<z-2;i++){
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    struct Node* temp1;
    temp1 = temp->next;
    temp->next = temp1->next;
    free(temp); 
    
    }



void print(){
    printf("List is:");
    int x;
    struct Node* temp1;
    temp1 = head;
    while(temp1 != NULL){
         x = temp1->data;
         printf("%d ",x);
    temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
   printf("\n");
}




int main()
{
    head = NULL;
    int k;
    Insert(2);
    Insert(5);
    Insert(4);
    Insert(7);
    Insert(0);
    Insert(8);
    Insert(5);
    Insert(6);
    print();
    printf("you want to delete:");
    scanf("%d",&k);
    Delete(k);
    print();
    system("pause");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please post text rather than a screen shot. Also the code should be the shortest it can be to replicate the problem, and runnable.

Comment: Please do not post [screenshots of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: For startrers: `malloc(sizeof(struct Node*))` -> `malloc(sizeof(struct Node))` or better `malloc(sizeof(*temp))`. Add your `delete` function is really fishy. I'd delete it and rewrite it from scratch, possibly by using a pencil and a piece of paper.

Comment: `temp->next = temp1->next; free(temp);` explain this to your nearest rubber duck. Why do you feel you need to change a field of `temp` if the next thing you do is `free` it, never to be seen again? Draw pictures of nodes on a piece of paper.

Comment: Another great approach is to type `"[c] linked list delete node"` into the search box in the header and you can find many good questions/answer with relevant discussion already. For example [Linked List Delete Node , Simple linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61468120/3422102) is a good starting place.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.   @Jabberwocky      Thank you for your answers, I changed 
  `malloc(sizeof(struct Node*))`   to   `malloc(sizeof(struct Node))`  ,   `free(temp) to free(temp1)` and the program can run successfully!I was too negligent.